# How to hide Methods and Properties that i wrote in Created Item Template after adding to project?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have question. I created a custom user control. My CustomUserControl is inherited from UserControl. I add some custom methods and properties in my CustomUserControl. I wanted to add my CustomUserControl to "Add New Item" in Visual Studio for projects.

For this I used "Item Template" and created a template. After restarting Visual Studio every thing was fine and I could add my CustomUserControl by using "Add New Item" in my project.

Just i have a problem when I add CustomUserControl to my project, the methods and properties that I am added into template file appeare and i can change them. How can I Hide methods and property in template? I don't want to see methods and properties after add CustomUserControl to project.

Note : When i add my CustomUserControl project, "CustomUserControl1" is created and it inherit from the UserControl not my CustomUserControl.

My Template is :

```
public partial class CustomUserControl : UserControl
{

    private string _Version;

    [Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    public string Version
    {
        get { return _Version; }
        private set { _Version = value; }
    }

    private void InitRequirements()
    {
        try
        {

            // ... My Code

        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {

            throw exp;
        }
    }


}
```

> After adding to project :

```
public partial class CustomUserControl1 : UserControl
{

    private string _Version;

    [Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    public string Version
    {
        get { return _Version; }
        private set { _Version = value; }
    }

    private void InitRequirements()
    {
        try
        {

            // ... My Code

        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {

            throw exp;
        }
    }


}
```

> it should be like this :

```
public partial class CustomUserControl1 : CustomUserControl
{
    // Without showing methods and properties
}
```

Thank you
Best regards,

Comment: Can you give an example of exactly what you are trying to hide?  It doesn't seem clear to me from your question.

Comment: Thanks for your respons I added example to my question. I created CustomUserControl and wrote some Methods insed it. And by using Export Template and choose ItemTemplate I put template to VisualStudio Templates. When i use AddNewItem over project i can see and choose CustomUserControl, but when i add it i can see methods and properties also and I can change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to hide the properties you don't want to display using the `new` keyword.

For example, if you want to hide the property `Text`, you can add the following:

```
[Bindable(false)]
[Browsable(false)]
public new string Text { get; set; }
```

**Edit**

If you want to reuse your control in other projects, instead of an "Item Template" you may want to create a library or assembly and reference it in your projects. Like this, you will be able to use it and inherit from it without seeing the code. When you use the Item Template it will just create a new `UserControl` based on the code saved on the template, but you are not reusing the `UserControl` itself. You could also create a NuGet package if you want to handle versioning, etc...

Comment: Thanks for your response i edit my question and i add sample to my question i also need to hide methods

Comment: Sorry, but your last edit is not clear to me, I thought you wanted to hide the properties in the designer. Not sure what you want to do and why it is not working, you should be able to inherit your CustomUserControl without showing the methods and properties in the child class already, this is the default behaviour and how encapsulation works.

Comment: No it is normal UserControl. I created CustomUserControl and wrote some Methods insed it. And by using Export Template and choose ItemTemplate I put template to VisualStudio Templates. When i use AddNewItem over project i can see and choose CustomUserControl, but when i add it i can see methods and properties also and I can change it

Comment: ah ok I understood now, see my edit, Item Template is not the good solution for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you so much it solved my problem. Thanks a lot